# Julia Convex.jl unbounded error

Tags: julia

I'm trying to calculate the spectral norm of `A`, this seems straight forward but the solver is telling me it's unbounded, which doesn't make sense, since `y` must have unit norm.

```
using Convex
using SCS
set_default_solver(SCSSolver(verbose=0))

A = [1 2; 3 4]
y = Variable(2)
expr = norm(A*y, 2)
constr = norm(y, 2) == 1
problem = maximize(expr, constr)
solve!(problem)
```

Am I missing something?

**Edit**: Removing `solve!(problem)` from the code (thus just setting things up), results in a warning that the problem is not DCP (disciplined convex programming) compliant, yet since this is just calculating the spectral norm of `A`, it should be convex.

Comment: You may want to try the Julia-opt list for this question and then self-post whatever answer you get back here.

Comment: @StefanKarpinski ok yah I was thinking of convex.jl issues but that seemed wrong, but your suggestion seems right, just so many damn forums it's hard to keep track.

Comment: The spectral norm is a convex function,
but the simple optimization problem defining it is not convex
(the objective is convex, yet you want to maximize it).
You can define the spectral norm as a convex optimization problem,
but it is not that straightforward: you end up 
with a constraint of the form "some matrix is positive semidefinite" --
for details, see
[Lectures on Modern Convex Optimization](http://www2.isye.gatech.edu/~nemirovs/Lect_ModConvOpt.pdf),
page 139.